# How to fix the number of repeat some string in regular expression?

Tags: regex

On this [link](http://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/regular-expression-reference),  I see this expression:

```
ba{2,4} will match baa, baaa and baaaa.
```

What if I want to repeat not only single character, but also a string?

For example, I want to catch matches like the following.

```
a3a/bBb/
or
aaa/bbb/c3c/
```

This doesn't work.

```
[a-z|A-Z|0-9]+/{2,3}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify you want xxx/xxx/xxx ?  Optionally 3 or do you want to match any sequence of numbers+ letters and slash ?

Comment: Thanks for answer. http://regexr.com/3b1h3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also repeat a grouping in regex:

```
b(ac){2,4)
```

Will match "bac", "bacac", "bacacac", and "bacacacac"

Comment: Thanks. It works!! I tried it before but failed. I can't understand. anyway Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

Given the regex

```
(\b[a-z|A-Z|0-9]{2,3}\/)+
```

And the input:

```
a3a/bBb/
or 
aaa/bbb/c3c/
```

It would match:

1. a3a, bBb
2. aaa, bbb, c3c

It would not match

```
aaa/bbbc3c/
or
aaa/bbb/c3c (the last one)
```